# Delphi. I can't even assign an integer variable

Tags: delphi

Using RAD Studio XE5.  I have added one integer variable, called `strand_pattern_length`, to an existing function:

```
function TDBManager.GetStrandVars(No_of_Strands, No_of_StrandLayers: integer;
                                  StrandPts: TRealPtRecAry; DB_its_a_Strand: TBoolAry;
                                  ProfileIDStr: string): TStrandVars;
var
  StrandVars: TStrandVars;
  i, j, k, n_l, str_count, colour_count, strand_pattern_length: integer;
  strand_pattern: string;
  Inset_dup, Inset_nodup: TInt_Array;
begin
  ... lots of code

  OpenConnect;

  runQuery('SELECT Strand_Pattern FROM ProfileSummary WHERE ProfileID = ''' + ProfileIDStr + '''', True);

  strand_pattern := _query.FieldByName('Strand_Pattern').AsString;

  CloseConnect;

  strand_pattern_length := 0;

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(strand_pattern)));

  strand_pattern_length := Length(strand_pattern);

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(strand_pattern_length));

  if strand_pattern_length <> No_of_Strands then
    ShowMessage('TDBManager.GetStrandVars : The length of the strand pattern (' + IntToStr(length(strand_pattern)) + ') is different from the number of strands (' + IntToStr(No_of_Strands) + ')');
```

The four lines after the `CloseConnect` statement are mine.

When I debug this and put a watch on `strand_pattern_length`, it displays a message of:

> E2003 Indeclared identifier: 'strand_pattern_length'.

The breakpoint gets to the `strand_pattern_length:=0` line, goes through that line (without assigning a value) and then skips past the `ShowMessage` statements, length assignment, and the `If` statement and onwards through the rest of the function.

I've declared all sorts of variables elsewhere in the project, and even elsewhere in this `.pas` file, and not had an issues.

Any ideas?

I have inherited this Delphi project, and although I'm a very experienced programmer, this is the first Delphi code I've worked with for nearly 20 years.  But surely assigning an `integer` value shouldn't be this difficult!

Comment: The compiler is linking a dcu file that does not match your source file. Hence the bizarre behaviour. You'll need to track that down somehow.

Comment: It is possible that you have two copies of the source, and that the one you have edited is not the one you have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

When building an application Delphi follows a two step process.
First every unit (.pas) file is compiled into a dcu (Delphi Compiled Unit) file.
Then the various dcu files are linked into a single executable.

Delphi will only recompile a source (.pas) file if it is marked as dirty (either because the file has changed or because the in-memory copy has changed).
If it does not detect a change in the .pas file it will instead use the previously compiled DCU.

If you make a copy of the pas file and edit the copy, Delphi will only look at the original file.
You can see the files that Delphi uses by using the `project manager`.

[image]

Expand all source files and hoover the mouse over the source files you want to check (or right click and choose `open in explorer`).
Note down the exact file path and compare this to the exact file path of the file that you are editing.
You can do this by hoovering over the file name tab in the editor.

[image]

If the path names do not match you are, in fact, editing the wrong source file.
Close the incorrect file and open the file that Delphi is using by double-clicking on the entry in the project manager.